# I'm unable to display vuex state values in a component template

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuejs3, flux, vue-composition-api

I'm using a composable function to fetch documents from firestore. I've imported the object returned to the Vuex store. When I access that firestore object in my components, I realize it's wrapped in a `ComputedRefImpI{ }` and I'm unable to display the values inside the template tags.

here is my **store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import getCollection from '../composables/getCollection'

function UpdateLocalStorage(cart){
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
}

export const store = createStore({
state: {
  cart: [],
  all: [],
  error: null
},
getters: {
  cartProducts (state) {
    return  state.cart
  }
}, 
mutations: {
  
  productQuantityInCart (state, product) {
    const item = state.cart.find(i => i.id === product.id)
  
    if(item)  return item.quantity
    else return null
  },
  addToCart (state, product) {
    let item = state.all.find(i => i.id === product.id)
    
    if(item) {
      item.quantity++
    } else {
      state.cart.push({...product, quantity:1})
    }

    UpdateLocalStorage(state.cart)
  },
  setAllOffersFromDB (state) {
    const { documents, error } = getCollection('allOffers')

    if(!documents) {
      state.error = error
    } else {
      state.all = documents
      
    }
  },
  removeFromCart (state, payload) {
    let product = payload
    let item = state.cart.find(i => i.id === product.id)
  
    if(item.quantity > 1) {
      return null
    } else {
      state.cart.filter(i => i.id !== product.id)
      
    }
    UpdateLocalStorage(state.cart)
  },
  cartTotal (state) {
    let total = 0
    state.cart.forEach(i => {
      total += i.quantity * i.price
    })
    return total
  },
  updateCartFromLocalStorage (state) {
    const cart = localStorage.getItem('cart')

    if(cart) {
      state.cart = JSON.parse(cart)
    }
  }
  
},
actions: {
  productQuantity (context, product) {
    context.commit('productQuantityInCart', product)
  }
}

})
```

here is **Cart.vue**

```
<template>
      {{ cartProdcts }} // displays all values as shown in the picture attached

      <div v-for="product in cartProducts" :key="product.id">
        {{ product.title }}     // this value is blank inside browser
        {{ product.subtitle }}  // this value is blank inside browser
        {{ product.price }}     // this value is blank inside browser
     </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
  import {useStore}  from 'vuex'
  export default {
   setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    const cartProducts = computed(() => store.getters.cartProducts)
    
    return { cartProducts}
  }
}
```

When I console.log the getter.cartProducts inside  Cart.vue, the correct values display as shown in the attached image but I'm unable to display the values in the template tags

[image]

Comment: can you create a stackblitz ? why you are using computed in setup() , "const cartProducts = store.getters.cartProducts" and then return to the template object ?

Answer (score 0):

setup method already return template variable, that can be used in the template, there is not need to add in the computed, vuex is one way data flow.You can get the value from store expose to the template. Without using computed this fix the issue

```
<script>


import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
  import {useStore}  from 'vuex'
  export default {
   setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    const cartProducts = store.getters.cartProducts; //  no need to use compute
    
    return { cartProducts}
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @kumar thank you but it's not displaying the values of a single product. My challenge the firestore returned object is difficult to access values as compared to a plain javascript object. The firestore is wrapped in a handler and target object

Comment: can you create a stackblitz?